My nextjs npm run build returns "Unsupported Server Component type"
My npm run build is not working while I can use npm run dev. Here is an errors.
C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat>npm run build 

Error occurred prerendering page "/profile/addData". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error: Unsupported Server Component type: {...}
    at e (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:138095)
    at ek (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:138145)
    at Array.toJSON (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:135755)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eR (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142219)
    at eE (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:142698)
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\sawettachats\receiving-mat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:150397)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ✓ Generating static pages (8/8)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /profile/addData/page: /profile/addData
        /profile/page: /profile

both /profile/addData/page:/profile/addData and  /profile/page: /profile  I use export defual to both page components and both are client side rendering. How to fix this problem?
I want to use npm run build. Now it's now working as I expected.

Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

"Now it's now working" - do you mean it's not working?
